# Android ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I don't understand why I have this issue.

```
03-21 10:46:40.739: E/AndroidRuntime(5114): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

Here is my code :

```
    headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.separated_list_header);
```

separated_list_header.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/list_header_title"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_emtheme"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="2dip"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

My application crash if I don't create my ArrayAdapter be giving the TextView id:

```
    headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, 
              R.layout.separated_list_header, R.id.list_header_title);
```

I'm doing the same in an another project, and I don't see this issue. As the root item of the xml is a TextView, I think it should work.

Edit: I found the cause of the issue, it's because this ArrayAdapter is used in another adapter ([SeparatedListAdapter](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/)), and then when getView is called, convertView is not of the correct type. So I bypasse the problem now by setting convertView to null to force creating a new view. This is not a good solution, because it's using too much resources, but at least it works. Now I have to find why convertView is not correct.

Here is the getView() method of SeparatedListAdapter which I modified:

```
    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int sectionnum = 0;
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

            // check if position inside this section 
            if(position == 0) {
            convertView = null; //Force creating new view because convertView is not of the right type
            return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);
            }
            if(position < size) return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);

            // otherwise jump into next section
            position -= size;
            sectionnum++;
        }
        return null;
    }:
```

Comment: once clean your project and try...

Comment: It should work, check that all your separated_list_header.xml (in layout-land for example) have only one TextView

Comment: @GopalRao I already tried to clean..

Comment: @CFlex Here is the complete code of the file separated_list_header.xml. So there is not any other item. in the file... Anyway thanks for your comments

Comment: @Gojir4 don't you have others `separated_list_header.xml` files in other folders? (e.g layout-v14 or layout-***)

Comment: @CFlex Nope, I even made a file search in the project folder to be 100% sure, it's the only one...

Answer (score 0):

Refer these [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20T%5B%5D%29)

public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, `List<T> objects`)

I thought you just missed to initialize the List interface objects.

Comment: This is not necessary, ArrayAdapter creates automatically an empty array. You can put some initializaztion values by using this constructor, but this is not mandatory. As I said if I do `headers = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.separated_list_header, R.id.list_header_title);`, it's ok

Comment: anyway you can try these one.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fix the problem. I found the cause, I will edit my post

Answer (score -1):

You should try to wrap the TextView with a layoutmanager (i.e. LinearLayout).

Comment: Do you mean in the xml file ? I have the same issue too

Comment: I would try to wrap in the xml layout file the textview with LinearLayout for example.